# PCI-e to PCI with flex cable

Tags: pci, adapter, pci-express

Need a PCI-Express to PCI adapter for a 1U server.  Preferably with a flex cable like this, but only need the one PCI slot:

[image]

Either that or maybe something like a 45-degree adapter, but I've never seen one of those.

Comment: Not to sound like a smartass, but what's your question?

Comment: No, I don't think anyone would mistake you for a smartass.  Try reading it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one [here](http://www.orbitmicro.com/global/arc1-900b-p-13383.html). "1-slot PCIe x1 to PCI-32 bridge-based active riser card for 1U chassis"

Your server vendor may have something appropriate as well. You may have issues mounting non-vendor risers in a 1U server, although with a fixed right-angle adapter it will at least retain some stability due to being mounted in a slot.

Another option if you have a low-profile PCI card may be to get a PCI-e 1x to PCI-e 1x right angle adapter (like [this](http://www.orbitmicro.com/global/pexp1-rx1-p-735.html)) and get one of [these](http://www.orbitmicro.com/global/p089-00g2x-p-8689.html) PCI-e 1x to PCI adapters

I've had custom flexi adapters (although not with bridge chips) made by [Adexelec](http://www.adexelec.com/) in the past. Very happy with the results.

Comment: Ended up (with a lot of phone calls) finding a PCI-X riser that worked.